# Tikz legend cannot be added?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend

I thought I can add a legend to a `tikz` picture by `\addlegendentry{...}`. But as soon as I uncomment the command the compiler complains about missing `}`. But when I comment the lines again, then it works. Could somebody give me a hint, why the legend doesn't work?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, intersections}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
 \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
  \pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}
%from matlab2tikz
   \newlength\figureheight
   \newlength\figurewidth 


\begin{document}
Sample plot with out legend?

\begin{figure}       
        \setlength\figureheight{2cm}
        \setlength\figurewidth{2.7cm} 
               { 


\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tiny]
\begin{axis}[%
width=\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
scale only axis,
xmin=1,
xmax=20,
ymin=0,
ymax=2,
title={Sample time series}, 
legend style={draw=black,fill=white,legend cell align=left}
]
\addplot [color=blue,solid,forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{1 1\\
2       1\\
3       1\\
4       1\\
5       1\\
6       1\\
7       1\\
8       1\\
9       1\\
10      2\\
11      1\\
12      1.5\\
13      0\\
14      1\\
15      1\\
16      1\\
17      1\\
18      1\\
19      1\\
20      1\\
};
\addplot [color=green,dashed ,forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{8 0\\
  8 2\\
  10 2\\
  10 0\\
};
%\addlegendentry{Window size=2};
\addplot [color=violet,densely dotted ,forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{10.5 0\\
  10.5 2\\
  15.5 2\\
  15.5 0\\
};
%\addlegendentry{Window size=5};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%

                    }

\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `forget plot` for plots for which you want to add a legend (`forget plot` is for plots which shouldn't be remembered for legend entries nor considered for cycle lists):

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newlength\figurewidth
\setlength\figurewidth{6cm}
\newlength\figureheight
\setlength\figureheight{6cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tiny]
\begin{axis}[%
width=\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
scale only axis,
xmin=1,
xmax=20,
ymin=0,
ymax=2,
title={Sample time series}, 
legend style={draw=black,fill=white,legend cell align=left}
]
\addplot [color=blue,solid,forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{1 1\\
2       1\\
3       1\\
4       1\\
5       1\\
6       1\\
7       1\\
8       1\\
9       1\\
10      2\\
11      1\\
12      1.5\\
13      0\\
14      1\\
15      1\\
16      1\\
17      1\\
18      1\\
19      1\\
20      1\\
};
\addplot [color=green,dashed ]
  table[row sep=crcr]{8 0\\
  8 2\\
  10 2\\
  10 0\\
};
\addlegendentry{Window size=2}
\addplot [color=violet,densely dotted ]
  table[row sep=crcr]{10.5 0\\
  10.5 2\\
  15.5 2\\
  15.5 0\\
};
\addlegendentry{Window size=5}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thx for the quick solution. Seems like that importing via matlab2tikz and editing afterwards is perhaps not the very best idea ;) Anyway thx a lot.